# Excel get sum of criteria based percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

It was difficult to word this question, but basically I have some data similar to the following, that shows a list of roles, their base rate cost, and a percentage.

I have added the Actual Cost column for testing and example purposes, however this data table is not editable, so I can't add the helper column:

```
Role        Cost    Allocation  *Actual Cost*
Role 1      1000    100.00%     1000
Role 1      1000    50.00%      500
Role 2      1000    25.00%      250
Role 1      1000    75.00%      750
Role 2      1000    100.00%     1000
```

I need to find a way to get the total actual cost per role, without the use of a helper column.

So from this example I could simply use `=sumif(A2:A5, "Role 1", D2:D5)`, giving me

```
Role 1      2250
Role 2      1250
```

But what I need to use is, the `=sum(if(A:A = "Role 1", B:B*C:C))` I know this sum function makes no sence, it is aimed at describing the outcome.

If this is not clear please comment and I will amend the best I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the sum function you've described makes perfect sense. You just need to input it as an **array formula**. Simply enter it as above, `=sum(if(A:A = "Role 1", B:B*C:C))`, and press <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd> to mark it as an array formula.

Note that if you have a lot of these, all referencing complete columns (`B:B` etc.), the calculation may be sluggish. You can overcome this by using the `B2:B5` syntax (but then of course you need to remember to update it when you add more rows).

Comment: Perfect thank you! I actually missed a bit from the questions and it is based on multiple criteria, will nested `IF`s be suitable to elaborate, `{=sum(IF(A:A = "Role 1", IF(E:E = "BR", B:B*C:C)))}`. This works, but is it efficient. I will be replacing all `A:A` with specific ranges.

Comment: Yes, or you might be able to use `AND` to specify multiple criteria - `=sum(IF(AND(A:A = "Role 1", E:E = "BR"), B:B*C:C))` (untested).

Answer (score 1):

As bensheperd has already answered, your formula makes sense. Just enter it as an array formula (finish by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER).

Or you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:
`SUMPRODUCT((A:A = "Role 1")*B:B*C:C)`
Especially for larger datasets it'll quicker compared to array formula.